# Aggregate columns based on values and sum

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Tipperary','Tipperary','Cork','Dublin'],
                     'Deaths': [11,33,44,55]}
)
```

I have this problem on a much larger scale but for readability I have created a smaller version, what groupby logic do i need to group by the Area column and sum, meaning I end up with 3 rows as opposed to 4 because Tipperary is in there twice. Say if I had 6 columns altogether how would I do this and keep my existing dataframe as it is? IE just reduce the row count because of the duplicated values in 'Area'

Answer (score 1):

If the other columns have more than just numbers, you can use `.groupby` and `.agg` with different functions for each column. If you do not want to move the grouping column to the index, you can set the parameter `as_index = False` in `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Tipperary', 'Tipperary', 'Cork', 'Dublin'],
                     'Deaths': [11, 33, 44, 55],
                     'Text': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                     'Numbers': [1, 4, 3, 2]}
                    )

out = test.groupby('Area', as_index=False).agg({'Deaths': 'sum', 'Text': lambda x: ','.join(i for i in x), 'Numbers': 'max'})
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        Area  Deaths Text  Numbers
0       Cork      44    c        3
1     Dublin      55    d        2
2  Tipperary      44  a,b        4
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this in the morning

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `.groupby` method

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Tipperary','Tipperary','Cork','Dublin'],
                     'Deaths': [11,33,44,55]}
)

test.groupby('Area').sum()
```